# Name of menu in mail app

Tags: iphone, ios5, menu

I want to implement a feature in my app but I don't know the name of it.
So I don't find any documentation.
On iPhone it is a menu with buttons which popup from the bottom.
You can see this in mail if you are start writing a mail and hit cancel in the navigation bar. Then this menu appears with 3 buttons delete,save or cancel at the bottom of the screen.
How is this menu named and how can I implement this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's [UIActionSheet](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/).